# Infinispan configuration with Wilfdfly-Swarm

Tags: java-ee-7, infinispan, wildfly-swarm

I have a project on Wildfly-Swarm. I need to use query cache, so I put Infinispan dependency on my POM.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.swarm</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I setup Infinispan on my persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="Condominio" transaction-type="JTA">
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>     

<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.infinispan.entity.expiration.max_idle" value="300000"/>
...
<properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

It's work well, the cache works. But I read the documentation of Infinispan Wildfly-Swarm fraction (https://reference.wildfly-swarm.io/fractions/infinispan.html) and I was in doubt if should setup it on project-defaults.yml using those configurations.

I don't know which configurations of Infinispan Wildfly-Swarm fraction are equivalents to persistence.xml configurations.

Comment: Not something I've done personally, but I suspect they're separate.

For instance, `project-defaults.yml` would be used to configure Infinispan within WF Swarm, where as `persistence.xml` is used to inform Hibernate to use Infinispan as a cache.

Comment: Yea, agree with Ken. The default configuration of the Infinispan subsystem should be enough to enable JPA caching, so no additional configuration in `project-defaults.yml` should be necessary.

Comment: In past two weeks I've been working on Infinispan Hibernate Cache simple tutorials ([repo](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials) and [PRs](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-simple-tutorials/pulls)) showing what needs to be done to use Infinispan as Hibernate Cache provider in different environments. So far I have done local, wildfly and spring, but wildfly swarm should also have one (I've created [ISPN-8703](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-8703)) to track that.